# Advanced YouTube search

Tags: youtube, search

Is there any possibility to find YouTube videos using advanced criteria except text search such as all videos uploaded by users with only one uploaded video total and between 40,000 and 60,000 views?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot search YouTube in this way.

The only thing that you could do is use the additional `Search Options` and sort them by View Count.

[image: YouTube Search Options]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start to push you in the right direction (maybe using Yahoo Pipes?)

Youtube has Charts (make sure this is set to Worldwide)

http://www.youtube.com/charts/videos_views?gl=US&t=a

This gives the most viewed videos by

- Today
- This week
- This month
- All time

Let's choose "All time" for now.

Youtube data api has the feed for this.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed

The next step would be getting the

```
 <yt:statistics favoriteCount="158959" viewCount="571740242"/>
```

from each video in the feed.

Now you can *at least* use a filter module between 40,000 and 60,000.

For adding in the one uploaded video, requires actual programming to be done beyond what Yahoo Pipes does as a feed creator.

<strike>*Starting with the channels*, you can search for say</strike>

> facebook, channel

Not sure what the equivalent feed will be. So you may need a script that filters this section

```
 <span class="video-count">42 videos</span>
```

within the search page.

Seems [this is not possible](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79623)

> You can search for YouTube channels in
>   the same way that you search for
>   videos. All user channels with greater
>   than **two uploads** are indexed in search
>   results. However, if a user's channel
>   does not get indexed in the search
>   results, you can directly get to their
>   channel by entering the following URL:
>   http://www.youtube.com/profile?user=[USERNAME]